# Access service via url:port from outside

Tags: networking, firewall, port-forwarding, gateway, reverse-proxy

I have the following network setup:

Gateway/proxy and firewall box with Firehol installed 10.xx.xx.xx - Ubuntu
internal server behind the gateway 192.xx.xx.xx - Ubuntu

All traffic is routed through the gateway.

On the server are some services running which I need to access from the outside without connecting to the gateway and then to the server. For example, if I type in my browsers address bar the: I should directly get the log-in window of a service which is running the internal server. On a different port should be another service.

*Now my question:*
How do I set up a network like this? Can I use firehol/iptables and how do the rules look like? If not, which tools should I use? How is this process called?

Comment: **without connecting to the gateway and then to the server** what do you mean? when you try to connect to the server you will always be routed thru the gateway first. The thing you are searching for to achieve this is called port forwarding and NAT: https://www.systutorials.com/816/port-forwarding-using-iptables/ and https://serverfault.com/questions/326493/basic-iptables-nat-port-forwarding

Comment: here is a guide for network adress translation NAT https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-forward-ports-through-a-linux-gateway-with-iptables